# OpenLayers3: How to show a KML layer with the export to png Button

Tags: kml, openlayers, overlay, png

So... I have this script:

```
 <script>
        //Script1: Script de criação do mapa.    
        var map = new ol.Map({
             layers: [
                new ol.layer.Tile({
                    source: new ol.source.OSM()
                }),
              new ol.layer.Vector({
                    source: new ol.source.Vector({
                        url: 'data/geojson/countries.geojson',
                        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
                    })
                })
            ],
            target: 'map',
            controls: ol.control.defaults({
                attributionOptions: /** @type {olx.control.AttributionOptions} */ ({
                    collapsible: false
                })
            }),
            view: new ol.View({
                center: [-5462834.47, -3058929.70],
                zoom: 8
            })
        });
        //FIM SCRIPT1.

        //Script2: Script para exportar o mapa em visualização para uma imagem formato PNG
        var exportPNGElement = document.getElementById('export-png');

        if ('download' in exportPNGElement) {
            exportPNGElement.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                map.once('postcompose', function (event) {
                    var canvas = event.context.canvas;
                    exportPNGElement.href = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
                });
                map.renderSync();
            }, false);
        } else {
            var info = document.getElementById('no-download');
            /**
             * display error message
             */
            info.style.display = '';
        }
        //FIM SCRIPT2.

        //Script3: Criação das Camadas KML. Bairros, Zonas, Perimetros, etc.
        var vilanova = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("KML", {
            strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
            protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                url: "../wp-content/uploads/2015/01/VILA-NOVA.kml",
                format: new OpenLayers.Format.KML({
                    extractStyles: true,
                    extractAttributes: true,
                    maxDepth: 2,
                    setVisibility: true
                })
            })
        });           
        //FIM SCRIPT3.

        //Script4: Ativa e desativa as camadas KML.                      
        function bairros(i, layername) {
            if (i.checked === true) {
                map.addLayer(eval(layername));
            }
            else {
                map.removeLayer(eval(layername));
            }
        }
        //FIM SCRIPT4.
    </script>
```

All I want to do is to show the KML layer and the export to PNG button. I have these two examples working properly apart. But when I try to merge them... they don't work at all.

The button still works (Export-PNG), but the KML layer does not. I have a checkbox to show and hide the "vilanova.kml" Every time I check the box to show the KML layer, the map freezes and when I uncheck it the map goes to wherever I dragged it before (when it was frozen).

Anyone already had a similar problem?

The KML layer example I got from another website. The "export to png" example/button I got from the OpenLayers Examples.

---

So... here's another script...

Everything is working. The KML layer can be shown and stuff... and I can draw polygons... All I want to do now is to export the map as a PNG.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--FUNCIONANDO!!!-->
<html>
<head><title>OpenLayers KML Example</title>
    <style>
        #map {
            height: 400px;
            width: 1000px;
        }
        .ol-attribution a {
            color: black;
        }            
    </style>
    <script src="http://www.openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ol3/3.4.0/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ol3/3.4.0/ol.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <br>      
    <div id="mydiv">
        <div class="container-fluid">

            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span12">
                    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
                    <div id="no-download" class="alert alert-error" style="display: none">
                        This example requires a browser that supports the
                        <a href="http://caniuse.com/#feat=download">link download</a> attribute.
                    </div>
                    <a id="export-png" class="btn" download="map.png"><i class="icon-download"></i> Export PNG</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <form name="camadas">
            <input type="checkbox" class="camadas" name="vilanova" id="vilanova" onChange="bairros(this, 'vilanova')"/> Vila Nova            
        </form>            
        <div style="font-weight: bold">Camada de Edição</div>
        <select id="mapMode" name="mapMode" size="1" onchange="changeMapMode(this.value);">
            <option value="none" selected>Navegar pelo Mapa</option>
            <option value="polygon">Criar Polígonos</option>
            <option value="point">Criar Pontos</option>
            <option value="modify">Modificar Pontos/Poligonos ja criados</option>
            <!--<option value="point">Draw Point</option>-->
            <!--<option value="box">Draw Box</option>-->
            <!--<option value="circle">Draw Circle</option>-->
            <option value="select">Selecionar Objetos</option>
        </select>
        <input type="button" value="download" id="export-png" onClick="convertasbinaryimage()"/>     
    </div>    
    <script>
        map = new OpenLayers.Map("map"); 
        map.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM());
        var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(-5462834.47, -3058929.70)
                .transform(
                // new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), // transform from WGS 1984
                   map.getProjectionObject() // to Spherical Mercator Projection
                );
        var zoom = 2;
        map.setCenter(lonLat, zoom);
        drawingLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Drawing layer");
        drawingLayer.events.on({
            'featureselected': function (feature) {
                updateFeatureTable(this.selectedFeatures);
            },
            'featureunselected': function (feature) {
                updateFeatureTable(this.selectedFeatures);
            }
        });
        map.addLayer(drawingLayer);

        drawingControls = {
            polygon: new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(drawingLayer, OpenLayers.Handler.Polygon, {
                eventListeners: {
                    "featureadded": controlFeatureHandler
                }
            }),
            point: new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(drawingLayer, OpenLayers.Handler.Point),
            modify: new OpenLayers.Control.ModifyFeature(drawingLayer, OpenLayers.Handler.dragComplete),
            select: new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(
                    drawingLayer,
                    {
                        clickout: false, toggle: false,
                        multiple: false, hover: false,
                        toggleKey: "ctrlKey", // ctrl key removes from selection
                        multipleKey: "shiftKey", // shift key adds to selection
                        box: true
                    }
            )
        };

        for (var key in drawingControls) {
            map.addControl(drawingControls[key]);
        }

        var highlightCtrl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(drawingLayer, {
            hover: true,
            highlightOnly: true,
            renderIntent: "temporary",
            eventListeners: {
                //beforefeaturehighlighted: report,
                featurehighlighted: report,
                featureunhighlighted: unReport
            }
        });
        map.addControl(highlightCtrl);
        highlightCtrl.activate();

        function report(e) {
            //OpenLayers.Console.log(e.type, e.feature.id);
            document.getElementById('highlighted').innerHTML = e.feature.id;
        }
        ;
        function unReport(e) {
            //OpenLayers.Console.log(e.type, e.feature.id);
            document.getElementById('highlighted').innerHTML = "";
        }
        ;

        function changeMapMode(value) {
            for (var key in drawingControls) {
                var control = drawingControls[key];
                if (value == key) {
                    control.activate();
                } else {
                    control.deactivate();
                }
            }
        }
        function controlFeatureHandler(event) {
        }

        function updateFeatureTable(featureList) {
            var wkt = new OpenLayers.Format.WKT();
            var table = "<table border='1'>";
            for (var key in featureList) {
                table += "<tr><td>";
                table += featureList[key].id;
                table += "</td><td>";
                table += wkt.write(featureList[key]);
                table += "</td></tr>";
            }
            table += "</table>";
            document.getElementById('featureTable').innerHTML = table;
        }

        //Declaração de Camadas KML
        var vilanova = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("KML", {
            strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
            protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                url: "../wp-content/uploads/2015/01/VILA-NOVA.kml",
                format: new OpenLayers.Format.KML({
                    extractStyles: true,
                    extractAttributes: true,
                    maxDepth: 2,
                    setVisibility: true
                })
            })
        });

//Centro do mapa e zoom

        var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(-5462834.47, -3058929.70)
                .transform(
                //new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), // transform from WGS 1984
                map.getProjectionObject() // to Spherical Mercator Projection
                );
        var zoom = 2;
        map.setCenter(lonLat, zoom);
        //Add a selector control to the kmllayer with popup functions
        var controls = {
            selector: new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(kmllayer, {onSelect: createPopup, onUnselect: destroyPopup})
        };
        function createPopup(feature) {
            feature.popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("pop",
                    feature.geometry.getBounds().getCenterLonLat(),
                    null,
                    '<div class="markerContent">' + feature.attributes.description + '</div>',
                    null,
                    true,
                    function () {
                        controls['selector'].unselectAll();
                    }
            );
            //feature.popup.closeOnMove = true;
            map.addPopup(feature.popup);
        }

        function destroyPopup(feature) {
            feature.popup.destroy();
            feature.popup = null;
        }

        map.addControl(controls['selector']);
        controls['selector'].activate();

        function bairros(i, layername) {
            if (i.checked === true) {
                map.addLayer(eval(layername));
            }
            else {
                map.removeLayer(eval(layername));
            }
        }

        //Add the vector layer
        var polygonLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("My Polygon");
        //Add the layer to map
        map.addLayer(polygonLayer);

        //Drawing controls
        drawControls = {
            polygon: new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(polygonLayer, OpenLayers.Handler.Polygon)
        };
        //Add the drawing control to polygon
        map.addControl(drawControls.polygon);

        //Activate the drawing control
        drawControls.polygon.activate();

        //You can add the select control to the polygons
        //This is not a necessary step
        var options = {
            hover: false
        };
        var select = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(polygonLayer, options);
        select.onSelect = function (e) {
            var mapProjv = map.getProjectionObject();
            var epsg4326v = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
            var verticesNative = e.geometry.getVertices();
            var verticesLatLon = [];
            var verticesStr = "";
            for (var x in verticesNative) {
                verticesLatLon.push(verticesNative[x].clone().transform(mapProjv, epsg4326v));
                verticesStr += verticesLatLon[x].toShortString() + ";";
            }
            document.getElementById("verticesStr").innerHTML = "Area Vertices: " + verticesStr;
        }
        //Add the select control to the map
        map.addControl(select);
        //Activate the select control
        select.activate();

        var exportPNGElement = document.getElementById('export-png');

        if ('download' in exportPNGElement) {
            exportPNGElement.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                map.once('postcompose', function (event) {
                    var canvas = event.context.canvas;
                    exportPNGElement.href = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
                });
                map.renderSync();
            }, false);
        } else {
            var info = document.getElementById('no-download');
            /**
             * display error message
             */
            info.style.display = '';
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And now... can anyone help me?

You guys can test it here:
http://www.jourdan.org.br/geojourdan-teste/

Comment: PS: here's the link to the map, on my website.
http://www.jourdan.org.br/geojourdan-teste/

Comment: Can anyone helo me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Checking your application I found a problem in your function bairros. The second parameter is a string (the layer name) for the map.addLayer you have to pass the vector layer object not the name.

```
<form name="camadas">
    <input type="checkbox" class="camadas" name="vilanova" id="vilanova" onChange="bairros(this, 'vilanova')"/> Vila Nova
    <input type="checkbox" class="camadas" name="vilalenzi" id="vilalenzi" onChange="bairros(this, 'vilalenzi')"/> Vila Lenzi
    <input type="checkbox" class="camadas" name="vilalalau" id="vilalalau" onChange="bairros(this, 'vilalalau')"/> Vila Lalau
    <input type="checkbox" class="camadas" name="vilabaependi" id="vilabaependi" onChange="bairros(this, 'vilabaependi')"/> Vila Baependi
</form>
```

Remove the single quotes in the function call:

```
<form name="camadas">
    <input type="checkbox" class="camadas" name="vilanova" id="vilanova" onChange="bairros(this, vilanova)"/> Vila Nova
    <input type="checkbox" class="camadas" name="vilalenzi" id="vilalenzi" onChange="bairros(this, vilalenzi)"/> Vila Lenzi
    <input type="checkbox" class="camadas" name="vilalalau" id="vilalalau" onChange="bairros(this, vilalalau)"/> Vila Lalau
    <input type="checkbox" class="camadas" name="vilabaependi" id="vilabaependi" onChange="bairros(this, vilabaependi)"/> Vila Baependi
</form>
```

In function bairros no need for eval:

```
    function bairros(i, layername) {
        if (i.checked === true) {
            map.addLayer(layername);
        }
        else {
            map.removeLayer(layername);
        }
    }
```

You had better to use jQuery to separate HTML and Javascript and $(document).ready(....) to define your event handlers.